# React: render new page/component

Tags: reactjs, components

I created a Landing Page for my (Timer) App, and I want to render a new page once I click on the GO button:

```
<Link to="/TimerScreen"
        id="goButton">GO</Link>
```

When I click on the button it renders an empty page, but is should have a page with a h1 TEST on it:

```
import React from 'react';
class TimerScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
               <h1>test</h1>
                   </div>
      );  }  }
export default TimerScreen;
```

Full code available on github /FilipZafran/Interval-Timer

Comment: Provide the full code base here or else share the click through github link

Comment: https://github.com/FilipZafran/Interval-Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.js route path code

```
 return (
<Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/timerScreen"></Route>
       <Route path="/">
    <Settings/>
  </Route>
    </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Change like and try

```
<Router>
  <nav>
     <Link to="/timescreen">timescreen</Link> //link the components here
  </nav>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/timescreen"></Route> //  define components inside switch statement
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your route path is different from what you specify in link. It matters](https://github.com/FilipZafran/Interval-Timer/blob/master/src/App.js)

```
 <Route path="/timerScreen">


      </Route>
```

```
<Link to="/TimerScreen"
        id="goButton">GO</Link>
```